# how to assign color depending on the elements of a list

Tags: flutter, listview, colors

I want to assign a different color depending on the elements of a list that displays the days of the week (from DB Supabase).
I tested the random, it's good but I would like to assign a specific color for each day of the week.
A track ?

[image: capture écran]

Comment: Can you provide the code that builds the list ? What you want to be the condition of the color ?

Comment: I use a ListView.builder and a ListTile. My leading is ContainerCustom.  My index is a string from my Supabase DB => index['xx'].

Comment: Ok and you want to have different color for different days ? The day is in DateTime or String ?

Comment: it's a string...

Answer (score 0):

To assign a specific color to each day of the week in a list, you can create a map of colors where the keys are the days of the week and the values are the corresponding colors. Then, when building the list, you can use the day of the week as the key to retrieve the color from the map.

```
final weekDayColors = {
    0: Colors.red,
    1: Colors.orange,
    2: Colors.yellow,
    3: Colors.green,
    4: Colors.blue,
    5: Colors.indigo,
    6: Colors.purple,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
 final List<Color> _colors = const [
    Color(0xFFFFFF00),
    Color(0xFF42BBF5),
    Color(0xFF00A500),
    Color(0xFF0000F5),
    Color(0xFFFF0000),
    Color(0xFF99FFF5),
    Color(0xFF000000)
  ];

  int getDays(int i) {
    if (i > 6) {
      i = 0;
    }
    return i;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                    Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: _colors[getDays(DateTime.now()
                                  .add(Duration(days: i))
                                  .weekday)],
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                                'DATE IS ${DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i))} ${DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i)).weekday}')
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's great. But I use a string and not a DateTime from my database (Supabase containing a day_of_the_week column), I just need to associate my day_of_the_week string value a color.

Comment: You could covert the String to DateTime format using the library intl. https://pub.dev/packages/intl
Add the String in your post that you are receiving in Flutter so that I could help to convert.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The date conversion is not a problem for me. I wanted to assign a color for each day that is saved as a string from another page (as text in my database that I use/test: Supabase, an open source alternative to Firestore). So I have a unique string value for each day of the week.

Comment: probleme solved; I finally use : color : getColor(item['day_week']),

getColor : Color getColor(String day) {
    if (day == 'Lu') {
      return Colors.blue ;
    } else if (day == 'Ma') {
      return Colors.red ;
    } else if (day == 'Me') {
      return Colors.purple ;
    } else if (day == 'Je') {
      return Couleurs.orangeAccent ;
    } else if (day == 'Ve') {
      return Colors.greenAccent ;
    } else if (day == 'Sa') {
      return Colors.indigoAccent ;
    } else {
      return Colors.blueGrey ;
    }